# Trying to find location of stores using lat and long from mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

Like a previous post which I got no answer from, I'm looking to set up a store locator using [Google]https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3 but I am getting no results in my XML document running this query;

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

There are more than 5 results that match this query and having ran the query directly in PHPMyAdmin to try and troubleshoot myself, I am returning 0 results.

Can anyone shed any light as to why this isn't / won't work for me? I've wasted a lot of days on this now.

Thanks lots,

Paula

Answer (score 1):

The radius provided in the tutorial is not enough.
If you increase it to 25000 instead of 25, it works.

Hopefully this might help anyone else in the future.